# C++ basics (Same code using other method (unicode?))

Tags: c++, unicode

So I've just started C++, so I'm very new to it, I now know most of the basic things. Yet I've stumbled on a problem with code I've copied from project 1 to project 2, they are now IDENTICAL, except project 2 contains "errors"...

So why have I started C++? Work asked me to create a Credential Provider, which you can't find any good information on the internet BTW...

Anyways, I copied to code into a new project and yet I have errors,
I've copied:

```
StringCchCopyN(pszDomain, lenDomain + 1, pchDomainBegin, lenDomain);
```

but project 1 is using:

```
STRSAFEAPI StringCchCopyNW(
        _Out_writes_(cchDest) _Always_(_Post_z_) STRSAFE_LPWSTR pszDest,
        _In_ size_t cchDest,
        _In_reads_or_z_(cchToCopy) STRSAFE_PCNZWCH pszSrc,
        _In_ size_t cchToCopy)
```

and project 2 is using:

```
STRSAFEAPI StringCchCopyNA(
        _Out_writes_(cchDest) _Always_(_Post_z_) STRSAFE_LPSTR pszDest,
        _In_ size_t cchDest,
        _In_reads_or_z_(cchToCopy) STRSAFE_PCNZCH pszSrc,
        _In_ size_t cchToCopy)
```

So why is project 1 using the NW function and project 2 using NA function, I did some small research:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
    #pragma region Application Family
    #if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_APP)
        #define StringCchCopyN  StringCchCopyNW
    #endif /* WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_APP) */
    #pragma endregion
#else
    #pragma region Desktop Family
    #if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)
        #define StringCchCopyN  StringCchCopyNA
    #endif /* WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP) */
    #pragma endregion
#endif // !UNICODE
```

Yet I have no clue why project 1 is using UNICODE and project 2 is not... Like I've said, the projects are IDENTICAL, at least, that's what I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because project1 has `_UNICODE` define at project level(check project property). So, define `_UNICODE` in project2 properties.

Here's how:

1. Right click project > Properties
2. Configuration properties > General
3. Project Defaults > Character Set
4. Change "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" > "Use Unicode Character Set"